# How to (optionally) suppress package welcome message?

Tags: packages

I'm working on a package and I want it to (usually) print a welcome message when it's loaded, primarily to leave a written trace of the version number in the notebook where it's used.  For example:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
Test::usage="Testing";
Begin["`Private`"];
Print["Test Package Version 1.0"];
Test:=Print["123"];
End[];
EndPackage[];

<<Test`
(* Test Package Version 1.0 *)
```

However this gets cumbersome in the documentation pages I'm writing, so I'd like a way to omit the welcome message.  Maybe with a semicolon, as:

```
Needs["Test`"];
(* silently loads package *)
```

However, the `Print` inside the package doesn't care if `Needs` has a semicolon or not.  Is there some straightforward way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Instead of Print your could just return your string after EndPackage[].

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I suspected there might be an easy way.  I'd tried including the string, but not after `EndPackage[]`.

Comment: @Kuba Have you ever used this in practice? I'd like to read opinions about how well it works in practice. I never thought of this solution, but it looks to be very useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems to work for me so far.

Comment: @Szabolcs I didn't have a use case for such message. Otoh the fewer side effects package loading has the better. Atm I don't see where this can lead to a problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs one issue might be with multiple source files and controlling what is the final result.

Comment: @Kuba IGraph/M prints a message because otherwise people don't read the docs. I even have special code so it wouldn't print this message when it is loaded as a dependency in BeginPackage. Just returning the message looks to be a much better way to do this.

Comment: @Kuba No issues with multiple source file, I put the return value in `Kernel/init.m`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moving my comment to the answer: you can put your message after `EndPackage[]` instead of printing it:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
  Test::usage="Testing";
Begin["`Private`"];    
  Test:=Print["123"];
End[];
EndPackage[];
"Test Package Version 1.0"
```

It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Reference from the documentation for `Get`: "`<<name`
reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and returning the last one."