# How to prevent IGraph/M from printing that annoying startup message?

Tags: igraphm

When I load [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), it prints an annoying startup message. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: See @Kuba’s implementation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200577/how-to-optionally-suppress-package-welcome-message).

Comment: @ChrisK Yes, it's basically that. I posted this as a guide for IGraph/M users, some of whom are annoyed by the message.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to link up these questions.

Comment: That startup message is not annoying.  -1 from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply suppress the output with a semicolon. The recommended way to load it is with [`Needs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html):

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];
```

One can use a semicolon with `Get` as well. `<<` is just a shorthand for `Get`.

```
Get["IGraphM`"];
```

If you load it as a dependency of another package,

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`", {"IGraphM`"}]
```

then nothing needs to be done. The message will not be printed.

This works only in recent versions, which return the message instead of `Print`ing it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200578/12